# Combine responses in google forms

Tags: google-forms

I made changes to a google form after I received several responses. They were minor edits like changing "yes" to "Yes" with a capital.

Can I combine the two sets of data so that the pie chart reflects all "Yes" and "yes" answers together?

Comment: No............ .